# Temporarily disable AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance running Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to disable my Asp.net application running on Elastic Beanstalk, but EB does not provide an option to stop/start the instance without terminating it.  I was going to try to add an "app_offline.htm" file and deploy to the instance to disable it, but Visual Studio will not allow me to publish the app to EB with that file in my root directory.  How do I get around this and disable the instance temporarily?

The reason I need to disable it is we are updating a 3rd party software that this application talks to and we don't want it to be making calls to the software during the update.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it would qualify as "disabled", but you could change the outbound rules on your instance's security group so that it no longer has permission to connect to the third party. (By default, the outbound rules are set to allow all connections on all ports.)